# Angular bind text containing a template

Tags: angularjs

I have, in my angular controller, a text like 
"For {{selDays}} days" 
which I want to bind to the view and have "selDays" changing.

I looked into $compile, but I saw that's mainly for use in directives.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it required that the text is in a variable?

Comment: yep. I have a slider which changes that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$interpolate()` can be used to interpolate the expression...

```
$scope.message = $interpolate("For {{selDays}} days")($scope);
```

But it'll only do it once. Use a watch if you need to reflect further changes to `selDays`...

```
var interpolatedMessage = $interpolate("For {{selDays}} days");
$scope.$watch('selDays', function () {
    $scope.message = interpolatedMessage($scope);
});
```

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/copoweyo/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: thanks, I didn't knew about $interpolate. Did the job perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write "For {{selDays}} days" in your view. Then you write selDays var in the controller scope. Each time you will modifiy the variable, the display in the view will change (data binding)

ex.

VIEW: For {{selDays}} days

CONTROLLER:  $scope.selDays = 42;

Comment: I need to use the same string in more than one place. So duplicating it would mean more work when changing it